# How do I duplicate/export only the visible part of a layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export

I've got two layers—a green one and a brown one. A little part of the green one is underneath the brown one.

[image: These are the layers - I need to get just the visible green part. The image shows the borders when the green layer is selected.]

These are the layers—I need to get just the visible green part. The image shows the layers' borders when the green layer is selected. Well, I need to crop (or duplicate as a new picture) the visible part of the green layer.

How do I do this? I'm not even a beginner in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution that I use in other programs (I don't know Photoshop at all, but since this works in even very simple programs, I'm sure it would work in Photoshop as well):

1. Let's say you have two layers: A (above) and B (underneath).
2. Create layer C (under B, so it's not in the way).
3. Use the magic wand to select everything transparent on layer A.
4. On layer C, fill the area selected with a uniform colour (eg. black).
5. Use the magic wand to select everything transparent on layer B.
6. Switch to layer C, and delete the selection. You should be left with a (black) shape in layer C that is exactly the shape of the part of layer B that is visible.
7. Use the magic wand to select the black shape in layer C.
8. Switch to layer B, and copy the selection. Then do with it what you need to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if two shapes really as two different layers, you can:

1. Duplicate the green layer (<kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>);
2. Select the brown one (<kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd>+click on it at Layers palette). You will have a selection exactly like the brown shape;
3. Select the duplicated green layer again and delete the selected part (<kbd>Del</kbd>).

Here you go.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to make it work through your method but It doesn't work. Probably I'm doing something wrong.

I can't find out how to delete just the part as you said in Step 3.

Comment: @Bakabaka, thank you a lot.  If you can publish a screenshot of your layers palette, I will able to do more specific comments :)

Comment: @VZ96 above comment is directed at you, methinks :)

Comment: Yes)) just can't add two recipients in comment